# Значение для динамического элемента

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

Через URL ко мне приходят параметры со значениями, которые я записываю в массив **paramsURL[]**.
Тогда мне нужно установить пришедшие данные как value для select.

```
$('select[name="brand"]').val(paramsURL['brand']); // этот select сгенерирован динамически. Поэтому jQ не может записать для него значение
```

**Вопрос:** *Как правильно задать значение для динамически сгенерированного элемента?*

Весь код:

```js
// Loading values to filter form
$('#filterName').on('click', function () {    // при клике на блок
    if (paramsURL['mtype'] > 0) {             // проверяем есть ли значение для этого типа
        $('select[name="mtype"]').val(paramsURL['mtype']).trigger('change'); // задаем его из массива и устанавливаем триггер change. Здесь работает на Отлично! Потому, что это статически создаваемый select
        if (paramsURL['brand'] > 0) {         // тоже самое с brand
            setTimeout(function() {           // сделал костыль через setTimeout
                $('select[name="brand"]').val(paramsURL['brand']).trigger('change');
            }, 5);                            // который сработает через 5мс
        }
    }
});
```

Вот еще работа триггера trigger('change');

```js
$('select[name="mtype"]').change(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/catalog/filter/brands?idtype=' +$('select[name="mtype"]').val(),
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
        success: function (data) {
            var brand = $('select[name="brand"]');
            brand.empty();
            brand.append('<option selected disabled hidden>Марка</option>');
            brand.removeClass('mark');

            $.each(data, function(key, val){
                brand.append('<option value="' +key+ '">' +val+ '</option>');
            });
        },
        error: function(request, status, error) {
            var statusCode = request.status;
            console.log(statusCode);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: "этот select сгенерирован динамически. Поэтому jQ не может записать для него значение" - отнюдь. Что-то Вы не договариваете.

Comment: @Igor действительно, забыл добавить код триггера. Поправил!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Значение для второго `select`-а надо устанавливать после того, как он *асинхронно* заполнен.

```
$('#filterName').on('click', function () {
  if (paramsURL['mtype'] > 0) {
    $('select[name="mtype"]').val(paramsURL['mtype']).trigger('change');
    $('select[name="brand"]').data("value", (paramsURL['brand'] > 0)? paramsURL['brand'] : "");
  }
});

$('select[name="mtype"]').change(function () {
  ...
     $.each(data, function(key, val){
        brand.append('<option value="' +key+ '">' +val+ '</option>');
     });
     if (brand.data("value")) {
       brand.val(brand.data("value")).trigger('change');
       brand.data("value", "");
     }
  ...
});
```

Comment: Нужно почитать о таком свойстве как .data("value", val). Раньше не слышал и не видел (: 
@Igor Душевное спасибо за помощь!!